# JOIN or INNER SELECT with IN, which is faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering which is faster an INNER JOIN or INNER SELECT with IN?

```
select t1.* from test1 t1
inner join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.id = 'blah'
```

OR

```
select t1.* from test1 t1
where t1.id IN (select t2.id from test2 t2 where t2.id = 'blah')
```

Comment: have you tried running it? or checked the execution plan?

Comment: I am using MySQL and I don't know how to use their profiler.

Comment: MySQL has the EXPLAIN syntax to review queries http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Comment: If those examples aren't translated to the same internal execution plan by the query optimizer then someone should be in trouble.

Comment: @LarryLustig: The two queries are not semantically equivalent. Let `x` and `y` be the number of rows matching the search condition `id = 'blah'` in `test1` and `test2` respectively. The first query will return `x * y` rows and the second will return `x` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `id` is key, these queries mean the same thing, and a decent DBMS will execute them in the exact same way. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't, as can be seen by expanding the "View Execution Plan" link in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e96/3). Which one will be faster probably depends on the   size of tables - if `TABLE1` has very few rows, then IN has a chance for being faster, while JOIN will likely be faster in all other cases.

This is a peculiarity of MySQL's query optimizer. I've never seen [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2e96/1), [PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c2e96/1) or [MS SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2e96/1) execute such simple equivalent queries differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to guess, `INNER JOIN` is likely to be more efficient than an `IN (SELECT ...)`, but that can vary from one query to another.

The `EXPLAIN` keyword is one of your best friends. Type `EXPLAIN` in front of your complete `SELECT` query and MySQL will give you some basic information about how it will execute the query. It'll tell you where it's using file sorts, where it's using indices you've created (and where it's ignoring them), and how many rows it will probably have to examine to fulfill the request.

If all else is equal, use the `INNER JOIN` mostly because it's more predictable and thus easier to understand to a new developer coming in. But of course if you see a real advantage to the `IN (SELECT ...)` form, use it!

Answer (score 0):

Though you'd have to check the execution plan on whatever RDBS you're inquiring about, I would guess the `inner join` would be faster or at least the same.  Perhaps someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

The nested select will most likely run the entire inner query anyway, and build a hash table of possible values from `test2`.  If that query returns a million rows, you've incurred the cost of loading that data into memory no matter what.

With the inner join, if `test1` only has 2 rows, it will probably just do 2 index scans on `test2` for the `id` values of each of those rows, and not have to load a million rows into memory.

It's also possible that a more modern database system can optimize the first scenario since it has statistics on each table, however at the very best case, the inner join would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases JOIN is much faster than sub query but sub-query is more readable than JOIN.

RDBMS creates an execution plan against JOIN so it can be predict that what data should be loaded to be processed. This definitely saves time. On the other hand for the sub-query it run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

[For more details please check this link.](http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/31/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect)